# override vim behavior due to plugin

Tags: vim, vi

When I'm using the plugin "python-mode" and I'm in insert mode, whenever press period (or "dot") after an object name, not only does the autocomplete open, but a help window opens in a separate vim panel as well. This is very annoying. I guess I need to remap the dot to it's default behavior in insert mode? How would I do that?

Comment: I don't use python-mode, but you can check what insert mode mappings are present simply with `:imap`  It may be that all you need to do is `:iunmap .`

Comment: But it seems likely that a large plugin like python-mode would have a setting to disable that without manually editing the mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the whole features of period, add the following line to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0
```

If you want to stop window opens, you should set `completeopt`.

```
'completeopt' 'cot'     string  (default: "menu,preview")
                        global
                        {not available when compiled without the
                        +insert_expand feature}
                        {not in Vi}
        A comma separated list of options for Insert mode completion
        ins-completion.  The supported values are:

           menu     Use a popup menu to show the possible completions.  The
                    menu is only shown when there is more than one match and
                    sufficient colors are available.  ins-completion-menu

           menuone  Use the popup menu also when there is only one match.
                    Useful when there is additional information about the
                    match, e.g., what file it comes from.

           longest  Only insert the longest common text of the matches.  If
                    the menu is displayed you can use CTRL-L to add more
                    characters.  Whether case is ignored depends on the kind
                    of completion.  For buffer text the 'ignorecase' option is
                    used.

           preview  Show extra information about the currently selected
                    completion in the preview window.  Only works in
                    combination with "menu" or "menuone".

           noinsert Do not insert any text for a match until the user selects
                    a match from the menu. Only works in combination with
                    "menu" or "menuone". No effect if "longest" is present.

           noselect Do not select a match in the menu, force the user to
                    select one from the menu. Only works in combination with
                    "menu" or "menuone".
```

You may have `completeopt=menu,preview` when you type `:set completeopt`. And as you see, `preview` option opens the preview window. So you should remove that option following in your `.vimrc`:

```
set completeopt=menu
```

Additionally, there is an issue with your problem, so you can track it: ["Disable new window auto documentation"](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues/384).

Answer (score 1):

That "help" is called "preview window"; you can read all about it in `:help preview-window`.